# How can I download and play audio clips without user interaction?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, audio, user-interaction

Is there a way programmatically to begin audio play before the user has interacted with the page?

With the following JavaScript:

```
console.log('Playing abc.');
XYZ.abc = new Audio('audio/abc.wav');
XYZ.abc.play();
```

I'm getting an error message,

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

When I click on the page, that goes away.

Is the standard UI pattern to request the user to click to start sound, or is there a loophole to do this programmatically?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So what the problem is that users don't usually expect audio to come from the website, so chrome requires your audio or video element to be muted by default. For the `<audio>` tag, you need to add the muted attribute, so -> `<audio muted>`

Respectively, the js element will have a .muted property. So, what you need is `XYZ.abc.muted = true;`

Comment: Thank you; I see you've commented on an HTML AUDIO element. Does the same principle apply between an HTML AUDIO and a JavaScript Audio object?

Comment: The new Audio() constructor returns a HTMLAudioElement, which basically is the <audio> tags' interface. Thus those two are the same thing. Using the .muted property should do the trick.